# SerialPort.BytesToRead return random number of bytes with EOL

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have an Arduino that constantly writes three hex's to the serial. My C# code defines two hex's (**0x0d** **0x0a**) or **\r\n** as the EOL. I was expecting each `ReadLine()` reads out 1 byte of data (**0x01**) plus 2 bytes of EOL (**0x0d** and **0x0a**), hence `BytesToRead()` should return 3 (1 data byte + 2 EOL bytes). `DiscardInBuffer()` then clears the OS's serial buffer to receive the next around of 3 fresh bytes {0x01, 0x0d, 0x0a}, supposedly.

But my `BytesToRead()` is returning some random count of bytes (e.g. 5,4,3,1,2,5,1,1,2,4...) while I was expecting them to be all 3's. If I remove or comment out **serialPort.Newline** (not giving the serial port a EOL), my `BytesToRead()` return all zeros (e.g. 0,0,0,0,0...). So clearly the EOL of **\r\n** (or **0x0d 0x0a**) is doing ***something*** here but not in any predictable way.

Could someone explain why I'm getting this random byte counts? I could probably write a function to manually concatenate and chop up the serial data with each EOL and store the bytes in an array, but I want to understand what is happening here and why I can't do this with just the **SerialPort** class.

**Arduino**:

```
void loop() {
Serial.write(0x01);   
Serial.write(0x0d); // Carriage Return, CR, \r   
Serial.write(0x0a); // Line Feed, LF, \n
}
```

**C#**:

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();             
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;             
serialPort.PortName = "COM3";             
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;             
serialPort.DataBits = 8;             
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;             
serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";             
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_OnReceiveData);

private void serialPort_OnReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string a = sp.ReadLine();
    int length = sp.BytesToRead;
    sp.DiscardInBuffer();

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        tbLogger.AppendText(length.ToString() + ",");
    }));
}
```

Comment: When you call SerialPort.ByteToRead, any number of characters might be received in addition to the line you already pulled.

Comment: so there is not such thing as EOL in .NET's SerialPort? I thought .NewLine serves as EOL and chop the stream for ReadLine()

Comment: Why do you expect BytesToRead to be 3? ReadLine consumes all received data up to NewLine, but there may be any number of bytes in the input after the NewLine at this time.